# xlC warning 'Initialization between types "struct {...}*" and "int" is not allowed.'

Tags: c

The following program om.c is compiled successfully via xlC, except for the warning about 1506-196！！

Anybody who can explain such warning information！？

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ch_sh[]="This is a program!!";
    char k1[1200];
    char *ls_sh=NULL;
    size_t len=0;
    FILE *om = open_memstream(&ls_sh, &len);
    fprintf(om, "   %32s", ch_sh);
    if ( argv[1] != NULL )
    {
        fprintf(om, "%26s", argv[1]);
        fclose(om);
        sprintf(k1, "echo %s", ls_sh);
        system(k1);
        printf("\ndone message in program\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: Empty input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    free(ls_sh);
}
```

Compiler log:

```
 1. root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp# xlC -o om om.c
        "om.c", line 11.14: 1506-196 (W) Initialization between types "struct {...}*" and "int" is not allowed.
        root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp# xlC -qsrcmsg -o om om.c
               11 |     FILE *om = open_memstream(&ls_sh, &len);
                    .............a..............................
        a - 1506-196 (W) Initialization between types "struct {...}*" and "int" is not allowed.

        root@psph:/tmp# ./om data1    
        This is a program!! data1
        done message in program
        root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp# xlC -qversion
        IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V11.1 (5724-X13)
        Version: 11.01.0000.0000
        Driver Version: 11.01(C/C++) Level: 100304
        C Front End Version: 11.00(C/C++) Level: 100301
        C++ Front End Version: 11.01(C/C++) Level: 100304
        High-Level Optimizer Version: 11.01(C/C++) and 13.01(Fortran) Level: 100301
        Low-Level Optimizer Version: 11.01(C/C++) and 13.01(Fortran) Level: 100304
        root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp# 
        root@psph:/tmp#
```

That's all！

Comment: According to the docs (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html) That should work since `FILE    *open_memstream(char **, size_t *);` is supposed to be defined in `stdio.h`, which you're including... are you sure that your AIX platform supports that primitive?

Comment: can you try manually adding `FILE *open_memstream(char **, size_t *);` and see what happens?

Comment: it seems like your compiler thinks open_memstream(char **, size_t *) returns int. maybe it's redefined in other headers? did you try compiling with only stdio?

Comment: I updated your title to quote the English text of the warning. I'd be surprised if anyone knows what "1506-196" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a warning:

```
Initialization between types "struct {...}*" and "int" is not allowed.
```

on this line:

```
FILE *om = open_memstream(&ls_sh, &len);
```

First problem: the `open_memstream` is not a standard C library function. It's defined by some versions of POSIX. The man page on my Linux system (Ubuntu 16.10) says:

> CONFORMING TO
>          POSIX.1-2008.  These functions are not specified in POSIX.1-2001, and are not widely available on other systems.

You might be trying to compile code written for another system (one that provides `open_memstream` on a different system (one that doesn't provide `open_memstream`). Or it might be available on your system, but you haven't provided whatever incantation is needed to make it visible. A conforming ISO C implementation is forbidden to define functions in standard headers other than the ones defined by the C standard (unless they use reserved names, which doesn't apply here), but typically there's a way to request conformance to POSIX rather than just to ISO C. If that's the case, the man page on your system should tell you what you need to do: `man open_memstream`. You might need to define a macro or pass a command-line argument to the compiler.

(This all might have been simpler if all POSIX-specific functions were declared in separate headers rather than sharing the C-standard ones line `<stdio.h>`, but there are historical reasons why that wasn't done.)

Second problem: You've also asked why you only get a warning. Prior to the 1999 ISO C standard, it was legal to call an undeclared function. The compiler would create an implicit declaration, assuming that the function takes whatever arguments you've passed it and returns a result of type `int`. If the actual function doesn't match that assumption, the behavior is undefined. The 1999 standard dropped this "implicit `int`" rule, making a call to an undeclared function a *constraint violation*. But compilers aren't required to reject code that violates such a rule; printing a warning and continuing to compile is valid. Which means that you should take all warnings from your C compiler *very* seriously.

(If your system doesn't have `open_memstream`, you might look for `fmemopen`, which appears to be similar. It's also defined by POSIX and not by ISO C, so the same considerations apply.)

**UPDATE** :

Since you're using `xlC`, I presume you're on an AIX system. Here's the [man page for `open_memstream` on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/open_memstream.htm).

I see there are no instructions for enabling symbols that aren't defined by ISO C. The man page includes an example. Here's a stripped-down version that should compile with out error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char *buf;
    size_t len;
    FILE *f = open_memstream(&buf, &len);
}
```

Please try compiling this example. If you get a complaint about `open_memstream`, most likely you're using some restrictive command-line option (try compiling with just `xlc c.c`) *or* you've hacked your `stdio.h`. If the latter, restore that header file to its original contents. If you didn't save a backup of the original, you *really* need to stop messing around with your system.

Also, if I recall correctly, `xlC` is the C++ compiler; the C compiler is `xlc`.

Comment: Thanks a lots to keith and All！

It seems that the declaration of open_memstream should be no any practical meaning in the stdio.h！ 
Because I have already removed the declaration of open_memstream in the stdio.h,  but it still can be compiled and run successfully w/o the declaration of open_memstream in my program source file！


So I think the first reason should be that compiler would directly find the function of open_memstream in the /usr/lib/libc.a by default！！

And the second reason should be as what you said！

Comment: @lylklb: Are you saying you modified `stdio.h`? Don't do that. It's provided by the implementation, and if you change it you can break things. If your system provides it, it should be declared in *some* header; read your system's documentation to find out how to use it. Don't try to use it without a declaration. And don't confuse function declarations (typically in headers, they tell the compiler how to generate a call) with the code that implements a function (in a binary library).

Comment: Anyway, I think the declaration of open_memstream in stdio.h is  just only a explanatory note！！

Comment: Notes: I just only removed the lines of  open_memstream  declaration  in the stdio.h,  then the program still can be compiled and run！！

Comment: @lylklb: If you think a declaration in a standard header is "only an explanatory note", you don't have enough knowledge to be modifying standard headers. You risk breaking your implementation in ways we won't be able to help you with. If there was an `open_memstream` declaration in your system's `stdio.h`, then apparently your system does provide that function, and you need to find out how to make that declaration visible to your code. `man open_memstream` should provide the necessary information. **Don't modify standard headers**. (I know what I'm doing, and I wouldn't consider doing that.)

Comment: Thanks again！ 
I know  what you mean！  And I also tested with your program source file, then the same results appeared with either xlc or xlC！
In fact my thought is that just only some specific function declarations(not all others), such as open_memstream,  are explanatory notes！

Comment: @lylklb: Function declarations are not "explanatory notes".

Comment: Doesn't it mean that the declaration of open_memstream is a exception that not takes effect in the stdio.h regradless of its POSIX-2008？

Comment: @lylklb: I don't think so. Your system supports `open_memstream`, so it declares it in `<stdio.h>`, and it has to provide a mechanism to make that declaration visible. Why would it be there in the first place if it never takes effect? You absolutely should *not* have to declare it yourself above `main`, and you absolutely should not be modifying your system's `stdio.h` file unless you really really know what the heck you're doing.

Comment: I find that the material cause is all POSIX declaration in the original stdio.h are not imported at all during the generation of its intermediate file,  even though specifying with -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L！That means you must manually add the corresponding POSIX declaration in the program source file if you want to use them！

Comment: @lylklb: No sane Unix-like system would work that way. I don't know what you're doing wrong, but declaring those functions in your own program is **not** the right way to do this. There has to be some way to make those declarations visible. You just need to find out what it is. One question you haven't answered:  why are you using `xlC` rather than `xlc`?

Comment: It would have been my "mistake" for long time！  And I shall correct the bad habit！
Notes: Within IBM VAC environments, almost all of the corresponding xlC(vacpp/bin) files are just the symbolic links to the xlc(vac/bin) files！!

Comment: @lylklb: Even if `xlC` is a symlink to `xlc`, it might look at the name to decide whether to compile C or C++. Check the documentation on your system; it should cover this.

Answer (score 2):

The warning says that you are affecting an int value to a pointer which is often caused by inderection level errors. And `open_memstream` is not standard C but POSIX.

Here, it is likely that for xlC, `open_memstream` is not declared in `stdio.h`. The compiler then assumes that it should be a function returning int hence the warning. You should ask the man (`man open_memstream`) to know in what include file it is declared and include it in you source.

Comment: stdio.h is implemented differently for every compiler?

Comment: @CIsForCookies : yes!

Comment: mind. blown. thanks! I thought FILE and such should always be the same, for any platform and any compiler

Comment: Maybe you need to set `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or similar to indicate that you want POSIX functions?  You should find the option that rejects calls to undeclared functions.

Comment: The stdio.h originally has this function, otherwise it cannot be compiled successfully!

And also redefining _POSIX_C_SOURCE not take effect !!

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with the posted code.

1. the parameter `argc` should always be checked to assure the command line argument(s) actually exist.  The compiler outputs a warning about the parameter not being used
2. the call to `open_memstream()` should have the returned value checked (!=NULL) and if NULL, then call `perror()` so the proper error message is passed to `stderr`, including the text of why the system thinks the call failed.

So, other than not using the passed parameter `argc` and not checking the returned value from `open_memstream()` the program compiles and runs with no problems.

Note the warning about `argc` can be fixed by having the following as the first statement in the body of `main()`:

```
(void)argc;
```

Also, it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  I.E. remove this statement:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

however, the root of YOUR problem is that the xlC compiler has a bug regarding initialization of arrays.  This discussed at: `https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2003-October/001009.html`

Answer (score -1):

Finally I have to manually add the following declaration ahead of int main，then it is compiled perfectly！！

```
FILE *open_memstream(char **, size_t *);
```

So the solution of Jean-François is right, but why this would only result in such warning without impacting on the final compiling and running！？

Comment: It would be worth figuring out what the proper way to do this is, instead of doing what you did  , there should be macros you can pre-define to enable this function in the stdio.h header